# Android compose - Animation at the end of Text line

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to add an animation at the end of text line. Unfortunately there is no way to animate part of the text (AFAIK) so I need to have some custom solution. I was thinking about having a text and then place animation based on the end of last line position. So far I came up with something like this:

```
var animationWidthState by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
val animationWidth by remember { derivedStateOf { animationWidthState } }
// This should be replaced with coordinates
var animationPositionWithinText: Dp? by remember { mutableStateOf(null) }


Box(
    modifier = modifier.padding(start = 16.dp),
) {
    Text(
        text = "Some long text that will",
        onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
            if (textLayoutResult.lineCount > 1) {
                val size = textLayoutResult.size.width
                val charactersInLastLine = textLayoutResult.getLineRight(textLayoutResult.lineCount - 1)
                val willAnimationFit = size - charactersInLastLine > animationWidth
                if (willAnimationFit) {
                    val bottom = textLayoutResult.getLineBottom(textLayoutResult.lineCount - 1)
                    val bottomDp = with(density) { bottom.toDp() }
                    animationPositionWithinText = bottomDp
                }
            }
        }
    )
                  
    AnimatedContent(
        modifier = Modifier.then(
            if (animationPositionWithinText != null) {
                Modifier.offset(need to come up with this value , animationPositionWithinText)
            } else {
                Modifier
            }
        ),
        targetState = state.value,
        transitionSpec = {
            slideAnimation(
                slideOutTravelInPx = slideOutTravelInPx,
                slideInTravelInPx = slideInTravelInPx,
            )
        },
    ) {
          Box(
              modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned {
                  animationWidthState = it.size.width
              },
          ) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = it.textRes),
                    color = Color.black,
                )
            }
      }
}
```

but the problem here is how to position this animation to look like the:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've managed to resolve this by myself.

First of all I needed to calculate the width of animation label. At the beginning I was using `Modifier.onGloballyPositioned` but unfortunately it was fired too late to get the info in in the proper time and also it wasn't taking into a consideration the different sizes of text, so I decided to measure the widest text before it's even laid out:

```
var animationWidthState by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
val animationWidth by remember { derivedStateOf { animationWidthState } }
var animationPosition: DpOffset? by remember { mutableStateOf(null) }

// Find the width of the widest animation text to check if it would fit in line
val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
animationLabels.forEach {
    val textLayoutResult = textMeasurer.measure(it, autoResizedTextStyle)
    val width = textLayoutResult.size.width
    if (width > animationWidth) {
        animationWidthState = width
    }
}
```

Then when I knew the width of the animation text I could use it to check if the label would fit in the line or if it should be moved to another one by going through these steps:

1. Get whole text component width
2. Get last line width (to check if animation will fit in this line)
3. Check if the result of subtracting the component width from the last line width is less than the width of the animation
4. If it fits - get the line height to know where exactly you should put your label within the text
5. If it doesn't fit - place you label outside of the Text component

```
...
onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
    // Calculate animation position to put it in correct place
    val textLayoutWidth = textLayoutResult.size.width
    val lastLineWidth = textLayoutResult.getLineRight(textLayoutResult.lineCount - 1)

    val willAnimationFit = textLayoutWidth - lastLineWidth > animationWidth
    animationPosition = if (willAnimationFit) {
        val lastLineWidthDp = with(density) { lastLineWidth.toDp() }
        val textLayoutHeightDp = with(density) { textLayoutResult.size.height.toDp() }
        val lineHeightDp = textLayoutHeightDp / textLayoutResult.lineCount
        DpOffset(
            x = lastLineWidthDp + animationStartPaddingWhenFitText,
            y = textLayoutHeightDp - lineHeightDp + animationBottomPaddingWhenFitText
        )
    } else {
        val newHeight = with(density) { textLayoutResult.size.height.toDp() }
        DpOffset(
            x = 0.dp,
            y = newHeight + animationBottomPadding
        )
    }
}
```

and then just change the offset of the animation label by

```
Modifier.offset(animationPosition.x, animationPosition.y)
```